# User not authorized to use transaction SE80

Tags: authorization, abap

I have downloaded and installed the **SAP NetWeaver Application Server ABAP 7.02 SP6 32-bit Trial Version** from SAP website.

I logged in with `DDIC` user account and wanted to create a program, but I couldn't do that. And I have read that I can't do that with `DDIC` account.

So I created a dialog user account, put it in the user group `DEVELOPERS` and when I try to go to SE80, there's the following error:

> You are not authorized to use transaction SE80

How can I authorize my newly-created account?

Answer (score 1):

Go to transaction `SU01` and add profile `SAP_ALL` to your user.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of SAP* or DDIC, you should be using the username BCUSER that comes with the trial.

See Page 9:
[How to Administrate the ABAP Trial Version](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/20db7e10-0bf2-2c10-3496-d5e7f9772c91?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&46566035437202)

To be able to do custom development at the system you'll need to enter your license info and developer key. You can get these for free at http://www.sap.com/minisap.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the SAP* user and use that user.